# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'train1'

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

Подскажите пожалуйста ! Как надо правильно разбить временной ряд для 3 разбиений ? Что нужно еще добавить в класс модели SARIMA, чтобы кросс-валидация с 3 разбиениями хорошо считала коэффициента детерминации(r2_score) ?

```
def f():
    %%time
    results = []
    best_aic = float("inf")
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


    for param in parameters_list:
        #try except нужен, потому что на некоторых наборах параметров модель не обучается
        try:
            model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(X_train, order=(param[0], d, param[1]), 
                                            seasonal_order=(param[2], D, param[3], 12)).fit(disp=-1)
        #выводим параметры, на которых модель не обучается и переходим к следующему набору
        except ValueError:
            print('wrong parameters:', param)
            continue
        aic = model.aic
        #сохраняем лучшую модель, aic, параметры
        if aic < best_aic:
            best_model = model
            best_aic = aic
            best_param = param
        results.append([param, model.aic])
        warnings.filterwarnings('default')

        return best_param, model 


class SARIMA():
    def __init__(self, Ps, Qs, ps, d, D):
        self.Qs = Qs
        self.ps = ps
        self.d = d
        self.D = D
        #self.qs = qs
        #self.Ps = Ps

    # close method
    def choose_SARIMA(self, X_train): # реализовать self
        from itertools import product
        parameters = product(self.ps, self.qs, self.Ps, self.Qs)
        parameters_list = list(parameters)
        len(parameters_list)
        
        # for param in parameters
        
        
        
        return #что нужно возвращать 

    def fit(self, X_train):
                      
        d1, lmbda = stats.boxcox(pd.to_numeric(X_train))
        best_param, best_model = self.choose_SARIMAX(d1)  
        self_best_model = best_model
        self_best_param = best_param
        self.model = invoboxcox(best_motel.fittedvalues, lmbda)

    def predict(start, end): # передавать сюда старт и энд
        return invboxcox(self_best_model.predict(start, end), lmbda)
    
f() 

s_obj = SARIMA(Ps, Qs, ps, d, D)#Ps, Qs, ps, qs)

s_obj.fit(df.train1)
m_ind = len(df_train1)
y_pr1 = s_obj.predict(m_ind, m_ind + len(df_test1))

s_obj.fit(df.train2)
m_ind = len(df_train2)
y_pr2 = s_obj.predict(m_ind, m_ind + len(df_test2))

s_obj.fit(df.train3)
m_ind = len(df_train3)
y_pr3 = s_obj.predict(m_ind, m_ind + len(df_test3)) 

v1 = r2_score(y_pr1, y_test1)
v2 = r2_score(y_pr2, y_test2)
v3 = r2_score(y_pr3, y_test3)
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

У вас одна и та же описка 3 раза:

```
s_obj.fit(df.train1)
          ^^^^^^^^^ правильно df_train1
m_ind = len(df_train1)
y_pr1 = s_obj.predict(m_ind, m_ind + len(df_test1))

s_obj.fit(df.train2)
          ^^^^^^^^^ правильно df_train2
m_ind = len(df_train2)
y_pr2 = s_obj.predict(m_ind, m_ind + len(df_test2))

s_obj.fit(df.train3)
          ^^^^^^^^^ правильно df_train3
m_ind = len(df_train3)
y_pr3 = s_obj.predict(m_ind, m_ind + len(df_test3))
```

А так у вас что-то явно странное с индексами для предсказаний, по факту у вас получается:

```
s_obj.predict(len(df_test1), len(df_test1) * 2)
```

Выглядит это странно, но я в `SARIMA` не силён, пусть знатоки подсказывают.